# Logs Missing in Google Stackdriver Logging for duplicate applications

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

Generally logging on Stackdriver has been great at picking up logs automatically from Kubernetes on GKE by going to Container Engine -> cluster -> namespace -> application name ("postgres" for example).

We have two groups of pods running a staging and production application in the Kubernetes default namespace on GKE. Only one of these logs to the pods' default application name on Stackdriver.

A snippet of the two truncated postgres deployment configurations:

**Production**

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: database-production
        track: production
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres`

**Staging**

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-staging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: database-staging
        track: staging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres-staging
        image: postgres`

Only one of these logs to `postgres` in Stackdriver, the other doesn't appear at all. I've tried changing the container name of the deployments with no effect. The only thing that seems to work is to host the whole application under another namespace but the [Kubernetes docs recommend against using namespaces unless the application is huge](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/namespaces/).

Is there any way to concretely define how Stackdriver Logging / GKE names logs via a Kubernetes deployment configuration?